# Quick question about a kind of morphism between algebraic varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm reading a proof where the author needs to use the Stein's factorization theorem. Reading this theorem, i've found the term finite morphism. What does it mean? Can someone tell me a topological definition?

Comment: topological mean without using the notion of scheme

Comment: When using finite morphisms, it is very common to reduce questions about morphisms to that of affine spaces, i.e. homomorphisms of rings. Thus you may be shooting yourself in the foot by avoiding the scheme theory in the long run. Not that this is a problem, but one should at least be aware that they are shooting themselves in the foot while doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Fredrik Meyer basically answered your question, but then his answer vanished for some reason. Anyway I think the best one can do in the direction you want is:

> finite = proper + quasi-finite

where *proper* means [universally closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_morphism), and *quasi-finite* means that fibres are finite.

Now you may argue that the definition of universally closed requires some knowledge of schemes. Well, sort of, but it's still a topological notion: see [the Wikipedia article on proper map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map) for the connection to the classical topological notion of properness.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f: X \rightarrow Y$ ba a morphism between schemes. Then the following conditions are equivalent:

(1). There exists a covering of $Y$ by open affine subsets $V_i =$ Spec$B_i$, such that for each $i$, $f^{-1}(V_i)$ is affine, equal to Spec$A_i$, where $A_i$ is a $B_i$-algebra which is a finitely generated $B_i$-module.

(2). For each open affine subset $V =$ Spec$B$ of $Y$, $f^{-1}(V)$ is affine, equal to Spec$A$, where $A$ is a $B$-algebra which is a finitely generated $B$-module.

If any (and hence both) of these properties are satisfied, $f$ is called a $finite$ morphism.